# On the topology of a Riemann manifold

Tags: manifolds

Given a Riemann manifold $(M,g)$,the Riemann metric induces a topology on $M$ which given by $d(p,q)$=the shortest length between $p$ and $q$,it's a metric topology,and my question is:is this topology the topology of $M$ as a manifold?If not,then what is the relation between them?

Comment: @C weid,you can see it as a proposition in the lee's book(introduction to smooth manifolds) in the section that is about riemanniean metric,you can find riemannian metric in the contents.

Comment: @RSalimiThank you I'm just reading it.Excellent book,rather suitable for beginners like me...

Comment: See answer here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612754/is-the-usual-topology-on-the-upper-half-plane-same-as-that-induced-by-riemannian.